# Insert an Array to a datagidview

Tags: c#

I have written a coding which extracts specific lines from a text file, split the lines and insert the data to a gridview. The coding is give below.

Unfortunately, when i execute this program, i receive an error msg called "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index". Please help me to identify what went wrong in my codings

```
string line;           
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("test.txt");

       while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           if (line.Contains("DISKXFER"))
               {
               string dataLine=line.ToString();
                   string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');
                   for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
                   {
                       for (int j = 1; j < dataLine.Length; j++)
                       {
                           dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = split[i];
                       }
                   }
               }
       }
```

Comment: Well error message is quite clear: index (`j` or `i` in your case) is more than items in `Rows` or `Cells` or `split`, respectively. btw, three nested loop definitely is not a great idea.

Comment: why not using addrange method?

Comment: I would say it is index J.  Does your DataGridView contain enough rows, do you need to call an add row method or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataGridView` does not contain the number of rows required to hold the information. Instead of setting `dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i]` to some value, you need to add one row for every entry in `dataLine`.

Instead of your nested loop you could do this:

```
string dataLine=line.ToString();
string[] split = dataLine.Split(',');

dataGridView1.Rows.Add(split);
```

Answer (score 0):

This page show you an example http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-datatable, for more information about datagridview http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview